# Wordpress Updating Author Meta While Saving a Post/Page

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I update author meta data while save a post/page? Any ideas?

```
function update_author_data_too($order){

$author_id = 468;   
$new_site = 'http://wordpress.org'
update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'user_url', $new_site);

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'update_author_data_too' );
```

Any ideas why that does not work?

Comment: Use `update_post_meta` OR `update_post_meta` instead of `update_user_meta`.

Comment: No... I just tried both.

Comment: I got it to work. Here is the fix.

Comment: function update_author_data_too($order){

$author_id = 468;   
$new_site = 'http://wordpress.org'
update_user_meta( $author_id, 'user_url', $new_site);

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'update_author_data_too' );